# Python Question about Variable Scope Rules

Tags: python, scope, quicksort

This is a source code for Quicksort in Python I found on Wikipedia.

```
def pivot(v, left, right):
    i = left
    for j in range(left + 1, right + 1):
        if v[j] < v[left]:
            i += 1 # .. incrementa-se i
           v[i], v[j] = v[j], v[i]
    v[i], v[left] = v[left], v[i]
    return i

def qsort(v, left, right):
    if right > left:
        r = pivot(v, left, right)
        qsort(v, left, r - 1)
        qsort(v, r + 1, right)

a = [4,2,4,6,3,2,5,1,3]
qsort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
print a # prints [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

My question is about scope. When I pass **a** as an argument in the example above, how can the function **qsort** possibly change the variable **a** in a global scope if it doesn't "call" 'global a'? I've been programming in python for 1 year and recently started learning C. Looks like I'm making some sort of confusion.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't *rebind* `a`/`v`, it merely **mutates** it. You don't need to declare a name `global` if you're mutating the object it's bound to.

Comment: What's important here is that `a` must be of a mutable class.  If `a` is an immutable class (i.e., a tuple) it doesn't work.

Comment: That's right. Seems that I'll have to take up Learning Python again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In python `a` is passed by "alias" (See Jochen's comment below).  Therefore, Any modifications to v will be relflected in `a`.

EDIT: I fixed my wording thanks to the comments below.

Comment: It's rather passed ["by object"](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) than "by reference".

Comment: No, `a` is passed by value. It just so happens that values in Python *are* references, but this is not directly comparable to "passing by reference" as defined in, say, C++.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I fixed my wording.  I've been coding too much C++ lately ;)

Comment: I'd never call Python's call system "call by value" or "call by reference" since that is just plain misleading for anyone who knows C or Java. I'd call it "call by aliasing" because that's what happens: The argument gets a new name in the function's namespace and that's all.

Comment: @Jochen:  I like that.  I'm definitely going to start using it.

Comment: @Jochen: "call by aliasing" - I like it, very concise!

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` receives a reference to the list object that is also bound to `a`. Within the function, the same object is bound to the local variable `v`, so any modifications made via `v` affect `a` as well.

Read up about objects, references and variables for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the *rebind* answer is a good one. It might be interesting for you -- since you start C, that you might want to familiarize yourself with the terms *call-by-value* and *call-by-reference*. Maybe knowing about those in advance will protect you from surprises:

```
void callByValue(int number) {
    number = number + 1;
}

void callByReference(int *pnumber) {
    *pnumber = *pnumber + 1;
}

void main() {
    int x = 5;
    callByValue(x);
    // here, x is still 5

    int y = 5;
    callByReference(*y);
    // here, y is now 6.
}
```

Be it as it may, also in C you find, that the parameters *number* and *pnumber* will **bind** to the real variables *x* and *y* from the outside world. In Python the fact that you have a list `a = [4,2,4,6,3,2,5,1,3]` will let you change that outside `a` by its inside name `v`. Just like `pnumber` allowed you that in C. In comparison a *tuple* would not have been mutable and would have been copied, i.e. `a = (4,2,4,6,3,2,5,1,3)` would not have worked. Just like in C the `number` is just a *copy* of `x` -- and therefore `x` does not change outside.

By the way, I suggest you skip C, but go right ahead and pick up some C++. Some things are just nicer there. For example, you can do it here without the `*pnumber` all the time:

```
void callByReferenceCPlusPlus(int &number) {
    number = number + 1;
}

void main() {
   int z = 5;
   callByReferenceCPlusPlus(z);
   // hooray, z is 6!
}
```

It might be a matter of taste, but it is really more straightforward, without thinking of the pointer-details all the time. Really.